# How to redirect a user to a sharepoint online site when using custom login

Tags: security, custom-login-page

I would like to have a custom login to my SharePoint Online.
 I can authenticate successfully by doing the below :

```
var targetSite = new Uri("https://<site_url>");
 var login = "<user@tenant>.onmicrosoft.com";
 var password = "<password>";
 var securePassword = new SecureString();
 foreach (char c in password)
 {
 securePassword.AppendChar(c);
 }

var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);

using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(targetSite))
 {
 clientContext.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
 Web web = clientContext.Web;
 clientContext.Load(web,
 webSite => webSite.Title);

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
 //Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
  Response.Redirect(web.Url);
Console.Read();

 }
```

But when I try do a response redirect like so
  Response.Redirect(web.Url);
 It still redirects me to the login page. 
Any ideas and do I need the AuthCookie and if yes how can I get it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Would love to know if you find out...